# 確認が終わった行を保護したい

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

#### やりたいこと

1. Aさん、Bさん、Cさんがそれぞれ以下の表へデータを入力します。
2. 事務員さんがデータを確認し、確認が終わったら✔をします。
3. チェックが付いた行のデータはAさん、Bさん、Cさんは編集できないようにしたいです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

#### 質問

関数でもGASでもいいので上記のようなことは出来ますでしょうか。
「確認が終わった行のデータは編集できないようにしたい」というのが目的のため、
「チェックボックス」の形にもこだわってはおりません。
別のいい方法があればぜひそちらでも大丈夫です。

#### 調べたこと

自分で調べてみたところ、シート全体の保護やブックの保護などは出てきたのですが、
任意の行のみの保護というのが調べても分からず悩んでおります。

色々不足している点があるかと思いますが、是非お知恵をお借りしたいと思っております。
宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: 「任意の行」という指定は無いけれども、「任意のセルの範囲指定」が出来て、それで行を単位に範囲として指定すれば良いのでは？ [スプレッドシートの保護、セルの保護（編集範囲を制限）](https://spread-sheets.com/useful/sheet/protect/) 手作業で出来ることをどのようにスクリプトにするかは課題でしょうけれど。

Comment: kunif様、コメントありがとうございます。
言葉足らずで申し訳ございません。手作業でのセルの保護のやり方ではなく、おっしゃるようにどのようにスクリプトにするか、というところが分からず質問させて頂きました。
一行一行保護していくのではなく、簡単に保護出来る様な方法があればご教授いただきたく思います。

Comment: トリガや対象範囲をどうするかは別途考える必要がありますが、セルを保護する処理そのものはこの辺の記事でしょうか。[【Google Apps Script】特定のセルを保護する方法](https://y-hilite.com/3286/), [GASでスプレッドシートのセルやシートを保護する方法(protectメソッド)](https://auto-worker.com/blog/?p=3220)

Comment: 返信遅くなりました。ありがとうございます、貼って頂いたリンクを基にGASを組んでみます。